# What is the difference between closed path and polygon in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I understand the difference between polygon and closed path in geometry, but I couldn't find what is the reason for using polygon column type in Postgres?

[Official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-geometric.html)  tell quite few and I haven't found anything consistent in the web...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few useful [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-geometry.html) that are available to polygons but not available to (closed) paths. So the real question is why would anyone use closed paths when they can use polygons? One possible answer would be the reduction of memory usage: a path requires 16+16n bytes whereas a polygon requires 40+16n bytes, which can make a difference if you have a lot of data.